# 'Symbol' object does not support indexing

Tags: python, sympy

I have argument A and tuple T and I assigned them values in dictionary named data. Then I created equation eq. Now when I want to substitute symbols with values I get error 'Symbol' object does not support indexing. How should I write code to get first value of tuple to calculate equation?

```
from sympy import *

A, T = symbols('A T')
data = {A: 1, T: (2,3)}

eq = sqrt(A*T[0])
print(eq.subs(data))
```

Comment: If you use `IndexedBase("T")` it almost works, but it seems the `(2, 3)[0]` remains unevaluated, and `doit` doesn't evaluate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If T is an abstract SymPy symbol, `T[0]` does not really make sense, "the 0th entry of some object of undetermined nature". This throws an error that you got, a symbol does not have a concept of indices.

There is [MatrixSymbol](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/expressions.html) class, which supports *double* indices. For example:

```
from sympy import *
A = symbols('A')
T = MatrixSymbol('T', 1, 2)   # matrix of size 1 by 2
eq = sqrt((A*T)[0,0])
```

Now eq is `sqrt(A * T[0,0])`.

You can then substitute for A and T[0,0].

```
data = {A: 1, T[0,0]: 2}
print(eq.subs(data))
```

outputs `sqrt(2)`.

---

When I tried to substitute `data = {A: 1, T: Matrix([[2,3]])}`, the output was `sqrt(Matrix([[3, 4]])[0, 0])` which, although correct, looks under-evaluated.

In any case, you don't want a tuple there; this is a rather different thing, e.g, in Python, `3*(1,2)=(1,2,1,2,1,2)`.

---

By the way, if your real goal is to apply some functions to an array of explicitly given numbers, then you probably want NumPy.

Comment: Ha I was halfway through wording a near-identical answer, nice :)